# Manipulating output of Select String Object

Tags: powershell

I wanted to manipulate the output in proper columns , so that I can later open the file in Excel.  Basically by copying the output and pasting it to the excel with delimiter option (Import Wizard).

SourceFile: a.txt 
https://rent.com

**Code**

```
$pat=@("rent.com")
$files=Get-ChildItem "D:\test\*.*" -Recurse
$files |Select-String -Pattern $pat |Out-File "D:\output\result.txt"
```

But the output i get is this:

```
D:\test\a.txt:1:https://rent.com
```

How can I manipulate the output, so that I get:

```
D:\test\a.txt~1~https://rent.com
```

Then I could use ~ as a delimiter and import into Excel.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$pat=@("rent.com") 
$files=Get-ChildItem "D:\test*.*" -Recurse 
$files |
    Select-String -Pattern $pat |
    %{ "{0}~{1}~{2}" -f $_.Path, $_.LineNumber, $_.Line } |
    Out-File "D:\output\result.txt"
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PY1NCsIwEIX3nmIoShRMqi5deQARbyBtndpAmpTJFIU2Xr3WKFk8@B68n849kXyDxkyiYe78Mc8JLavKtQJGcD3LWhuEQvGLp7umH8G4APBosGLpmbR9gLwWzEgWTmuRJjYxuBogG3bhPexnHUIGsoblTc2FZvuFs7Z46dsSKVkIsZn@y/hfFfynDw)

References:

[Select-String Outputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.0#outputs)

Comment: Thanks Doug, but the problem is that I could have ':' in the text  file itself .

Above command would result in 
D~\test\a.txt~1~https~//rent.com

Comment: Hi Doug, for the $_.Line column , is there a way I could get just the matched value rather than the whole line ; so the output will be D:\test\a.txt:1:rent.com , trying to see matches parameter.

Comment: The Pattern property will specify the pattern in the input pattern array that was responsible for the match. The Matches property will give detailed information about the regex pattern match including capture group results.

Answer (score 0):

Other method :

```
$pat=@("tec") 
$files=Get-ChildItem "D:\test*.*"  -Recurse -file
$files | Select-String -Pattern $pat |   %{$_.ToString().Replace(':', '~')}  | Out-File "D:\output\result.txt"
```

Comment: I had the same solution at first, but it doesn't work because both the filename and the result has a ':' which should not be replaced with '~'